# Devexpress WinForms Map Control - Get Geopoint (Coordinates) from address

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, bing-maps

I'm currently working on a project where I have a map on my form. The map is implemented with devexpress' Map-Control. I have some pushpins on the map, representing some important places. They get their locations via coordinates, like this:

```
GeoPoint location = new GeoPoint(47, 9);
MapPushpin pp1 = new MapPushpin();
pp1.Location = location;
```

I was asking myself if it would be possible to let a user type in an address in a textbox, which is automatically translated into a geopoint, and added to the map.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was asking myself if it would be possible to let a user type in an
>   address in a textbox, which is automatically translated into a
>   geopoint, and added to the map. Is that possible?

Yes, it is possible. Take a look at the documentation - the [Searching](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument17954) section includes examples that demonstrate how to provide a search functionality to the map control.

The complete sample project that demonstrates how to accomplish your task is available in the DevExpress Code Examples database: [How to: manually generate map items for location information received from the Bing Search provider](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/T188838.aspx)

Comment: I found also this demo: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument16711 but both, yours and mine, get me a nullreferenceexception in the line  ` BingSearchDataProvider SearchProvider { get { return (BingSearchDataProvider)SearchLayer.DataProvider; } }` which in my opinion doesn't make any sense, because the object "SearchProvider" is definetely not null

Comment: @Marcel: I've checked the example I mentioned in my answer - it works as expected to me. There is no exception. Please, try again. If the problem remains i suggest you contact the DevExpress Support Team and attach the "broken" example. I believe their guys will provide you with a solution immediately...

Comment: Thank you, I created a new testproject from scratch, and this works for me too...